# Why is data missing in request.POST dict on form submit

Tags: django, django-forms

On form submit I get the csrf_token and quantity in the request.POST, but not the tickets checkbox.
I have a lot more checkboxes but omitted them from the example.

Do I need to add the values to input elements under the submit tag with JS?

```
<form id="tour-form" role="form" class="tour-form clearfix" method="post"
 action="{% url 'tour:add-to-cart' tour_id=tour.pk slug=tour.get_slug %}" novalidate>
               {% csrf_token %}
               <strong>You are booking</strong>
               <span>{{tour.name}}</span>
              <ul>
            <li>
           <label class="custom-check" for="tour-form-tickets">
           <input type="checkbox" id="tour-form-tickets" name="tickets" value="1" price="{{tranport_prices_total|floatformat:'0'}}"/>
           <i></i>
           <strong>Corresponding airplane packages</strong> -
           <span>{{tranport_prices_total|floatformat:"0"}} €</span>
           </label>
          </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="total-box">
        Total <span>0 &euro;</span>
      </span>
    <input type="submit" value="order tour"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
</form>
```

The view is:

```
def tour_add_to_cart(request, slug, tour_id, hotel=None, shuttle=None):
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(reverse(
            'tour:details',
            kwargs={'tour_id': tour_id, 'slug': slug}))
    tours = tour_for_cart(user=request.user)
    tour = get_object_or_404(tours, pk=tour_id)
    form, cart = handle_cart_form(request, tour, create_cart=True)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        if request.is_ajax():
            response = JsonResponse({'next': reverse('cart:index')}, status=200)
        else:
            response = redirect('cart:index')
    else:
        if request.is_ajax():
            response = JsonResponse({'error': form.errors}, status=400)
        else:
            response = tour_details(request, slug, tour_id, form)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        set_cart_cookie(cart, response)
    return response
```

Comment: Please show us your view code and how you are trying to access this field from the post data.

Comment: Also are you trying to return "price" or "value"

Comment: @MasonStedman I need the price.

Comment: There is nothing in the view code that you've posted that is trying to access `request.POST['tickets']`? Also the `price` attribute on your input field will not do anything - if you need that data you have to pass it as the `value` of a form input.

Comment: Yea, if you check a checkbox the value is what will be returned, price isn't a property of a checkbox.

Comment: Oh my! If the checkboxes are not selected the form doesn't add them to the request...